# Swift - Cast from 'NSData?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails

Tags: ios, swift

I'm on the newest version of Xcode and I'm getting this error: "Cast from 'NSData?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails"

with this code:

```
let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)

let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

Programming Language: Swift

updated code:

```
if (error == nil) {
                let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)

                let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                }
```

- getting a breakpoint now when I run my app.

Sorry, i'm still new to stack overflow

Comment: Yes, it is NSDictionary

Comment: `let weatherDictionary : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)` use this code and check `weatherDictionary` is `NSArray` OR `NSDictionary`.

Comment: still getting an error

Comment: Please go back and edit your original question. Add an "##Edit" block at the bottom. Post your new code, and the EXACT error message you are getting, along with telling us which line throws the error.

Comment: "Its a breakpoint?" What does that mean?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - He should not use mutable containers unless he absolutely needs them.

Comment: @Python_is_cool - Two points: First, if you're having problems, do not use `nil` for the `error` parameter. This is a mechanism to let the parser explain why it failed. It's crazy to have errors, but not want to see what the error is. Second, you should convert the `NSData` to a string and visually examine it (perhaps editing the question showing us what it looks like). E.g., `println(NSString(data: dataObject, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))`. The problem will likely become self-evident when we look at the actual response string.

Comment: @Python_is_cool - As an aside, you really don't want to use `contentsOfURL`. First, if there's a network error, it won't tell you what the error is. Second, it's synchronous and you should only perform asynchronous network requests. Use `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL` instead. Let's see what the `dataObject` contents look like first, but you'll enetually want to tackle this, too.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it fails. You're calling the wrong method.

The NSJSONSerialization method dataWithJSONObject takes an object that can be converted to JSON and returns NSData. It will always return NSData (or nil). It will never, under any circumstances, return a dictionary.

If you have NSData that you want to convert to a collection object then you want to use the method JSONObjectWithData instead.

Comment: let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
                    
                        let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary 

It's still not working